# Extend an assiociative Array with variable

Tags: php, arrays

can someone help me, how I can extend an assiociative array with a variable?

I have a loop (foreach):

```
    foreach($this->getWarehouseListForm() as $wareHouse) {

        $wareHouseList[] =
            [
                "title" => "wareHouse[105]",
                "form" => [
                    "storeId[105]" => [
                        "type" => "inputText",
                        "options" => [
                            "name" => "TSL",
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ];

    }
```

And I want to extend a object like this:

```
                "sections" => [
                    [
                        "title" => 'Schuhe24Assistant.ftpServerTitle',
                        "description" => 'Schuhe24Assistant.ftpServerDescription',
                        "form" => [
                            "ftpServer" => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'defaultValue' => 'ftp.hisasp2.com',
                                'options' => [
                                    'name' => 'Schuhe24Assistant.ftpServer',
                                    'required' => true,
                                ]
                            ],
                            "ftpUser" => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'defaultValue' => 'username',
                                'options' => [
                                    'name' => 'Schuhe24Assistant.ftpUser',
                                    'required' => true,
                                ]
                            ],
                            "ftpPassword" => [
                                'type' => 'text',
                                'defaultValue' => 'password',
                                'options' => [
                                    'name' => 'Schuhe24Assistant.ftpPassword',
                                    #'isPassword' => true,
                                    'required' => true,
                                ],
                            ],
                            "deleteFiles" => [
                                'type' => 'toggle',
                                'defaultValue' => true,
                                'options' => [
                                    'name' => 'Schuhe24Assistant.deleteFiles',
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ], $wareHouseList
```

But this code produces nothing (no error output) and the structure check fails in this case. If I remove the variable, the structure check is OK.

Can someone help me out?

Kind regards
Henning

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show a [mcve] - some actual PHP code which you have run, the output of that code, and the output you expected instead. At the moment, it's not clear what code you're running, or what "structure check" is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Push your `$wareHouseList array` into the `$sections array` in the following ways

```
$sections['wareHouseList'] = $wareHouseList
```

It should be working.

Comment: Hi, the Objekt has many assiociations, and sections doesn't have a Index with strings. Your solution doesn't work in my Case.

Comment: Remove index, try this way `$sections[] = $wareHouseList;`